# How can I convert this API call to a data table in r?

Tags: r, api, datatable, finance, elixir-iex

I want to convert a call from IEX to a data table in R:

https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try anything? Where are you getting stuck? How about just `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols")`

Comment: New to API, no clue where to start! thanks for the head start.

Comment: Solution on GitHub: https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/iex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fromJSON` of `rjson` package then transform `list` to `data.frame`. Please see the code below:

```
library(rjson)
f <- (fromJSON(file = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols"))
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(f, unlist)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df)
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   8691 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ symbol   : chr  "A" "AA" "AAAU" "AABA" ...
 $ name     : chr  "Agilent Technologies Inc." "Alcoa Corporation" "Perth Mint Physical Gold" "Altaba Inc." ...
 $ date     : chr  "2018-09-19" "2018-09-19" "2018-09-19" "2018-09-19" ...
 $ isEnabled: chr  "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" ...
 $ type     : chr  "cs" "cs" "N/A" "cs" ...
 $ iexId    : chr  "2" "12042" "14924" "7653" ...
```